# Error al utilizar PDO::FETCH_CLASS en PHP ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Usuarios::__construct()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

tengo una select que utiliza PDO::FETCH_CLASS. El problema que tengo es que el constructor de la clase tiene una propiedad y cuando hago la petición me responde:

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Usuarios::__construct(), 0 passed and exactly 1 ....
> main}SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: could not call class constructor247

Si en la clase comento el constructor me funciona bien. Pongo código de la clase:

```
class Usuarios {

    public  $idusuario = "" ;
    public  $nick ="";
    public  $data= array();
    
 //    
//        public function __construct( $idusuario) {
//           
//            $this->idusuario = $idusuario;
//            
//        }

    
public function __set($name, $value)
{
    
    $this->data[$name] = $value;
}

public function __get($name)
{
  
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
        return $this->data[$name];
    }
}
```

Así me funciona me devuelve:

1
pedro
0
hola soy pedro

En la petición lo tengo así:

```
 $con = Conne::connect();

    $sql = "Select idusuario,nick,sexo  FROM ".TBL_USUARIO. " WHERE  idusuario >         :idusuario;";
    
    try{
       
        $st = $con->prepare($sql);
       
        //
        $st->execute([':idusuario' => $id]);
        $st->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS ,'Usuarios');
        $row = $st->fetchAll();
       
    
        echo $row[0]->idusuario;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row[0]->nick;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row[0]->sexo;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row[0]->saludo();
```

¿Como le paso el parámetro al constructor? Por que este es un ejemplo sencillo pero si necesito un constructor con 5 o 6 propiedades. Si en alguna parte necesitara ese constructor. Se que PHP solo permite tener un constructor, por eso pregunto como debería pasar desde la petición el|los parámetros al constructor.

Goyo conforme tú has puesto me construye la instancia con el número de id que le paso como parámetro al método, en este caso 0. Pero en la tabla hay dos registros con id=1 y id=2. Osea no me devuelve una instancia con el resultado de la 'select' que es lo que yo esperaba.

Más bien esperaba como cuando usas 'PDO::FETCH_OBJ' te pongo código:

```
try{
       
        $st = $con->prepare($sql);
        $st ->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        
         $st ->execute();
       
        while($row = $st->fetch()){
            //var_dump($row);
            $prueba = new Usuarios($row);
            $nick = $prueba->devuelveNick($id);
            echo $nick;
            
        }
```

Entonces no entiendo la diferencia entre 'PDO::FETCH_CLASS' y 'PDO::FETCH_OBJ' o el ejemplo de select no es el apropiado. Podrías explicármelo.

Y aprovechando el asunto. Por que en la documentación de PHP no aparece explicado así, osea no hay ningún ejemplo de hacerlo de esta manera:

```
 $st->execute([':idusuario' => $id]);
```

¿No lo entiendo la documentación no esta actualizada?En mi caso el ejemplo del execute lo vi en una página web no el la documentación. Me ha pasado con otros ejemplos.

Hola @Goyo David, no te he respondido este fin de semana por que no he podido. A ver el tema es que en PHP no necesitas un fetch(PDO::Object) para que te devuelva una instancia, pongo un ejemplo:

```
 public static function getMember($id){
    
    $con =  Conne::connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USUARIO." WHERE id = :id";
    try{
        $st = $con->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->execute();
        $row = $st->fetch();
        $st->closeCursor();
        Conne::disconnect($con);
        
        if($row){return new Usuarios($row);}
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getLine().'<br>';
        echo $ex->getFile().'<br>';
        Conne::disconnect($con);
        die("Query failed: ".$ex->getMessage());
    }
    
//fin getMember
}
```

Yo siempre lo he hecho así. Yo lo que no tengo claro es la difencia entre fetch(Object) y fetch(class). La única diferencia que se me ocurre es que con fetch(class) puedo acceder a propiedades de clase por ejemplo el típico contador de instancias ejemplo:

```
Class X{

static count;
```

}

Ya que como es una propiedad de clase un objeto no puede acceder a ella. No veo otra diferencia. Me podrías aclarar si hay algo más.

Comment: Gracias @Goyo David, me funciona pero me surgen unas dudas. Te pongo código arriba.

Comment: Tienes razón, en tu caso si deseas iterarlo lo mejor es usar PDO::FETCH_OBJ, mi ejemplo es si quieres pasarlo sobre un elemento especificamente. no comprendi bien que buscabas aunque tambien se pudo haber logrado de esta forma. Despues del $st->fetchAll(); haces un foreach

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que pasarlo por aquí

```
$st->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Usuarios', [$id]); // Pasar $id al constructor
```